# Using spring-webmvc-portlet for the first time, getting the following error (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid portlet request phase: null)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I've been banging my head against the wall with the following exception.  I'm using `Spring 3.1.3-RELEASE` and deploying to `Tomcat/Pluto` with associated Pluto libraries.  Has anyone been able to get past this exception?  Do I need to implement the GenericPortlet interface in my app?

Regards.

```
ERROR [org.jasig.portal.ChannelManager#156] portlet.DispatcherPortlet.[] Nov/10 09:56:45 - Could not complete request
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid portlet request phase: null
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:531)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:470)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:175)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.PortletServlet.doGet(PortletServlet.java:139)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.DefaultPortletInvokerService.invoke(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:167)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.DefaultPortletInvokerService.render(DefaultPortletInvokerService.java:101)
    at org.apache.pluto.core.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:172)
    at org.jasig.portal.portlet.rendering.PortletRendererImpl.doRender(PortletRendererImpl.java:232)
    at org.jasig.portal.channels.portlet.SpringPortletChannelImpl.render(SpringPortletChannelImpl.java:381)
    at org.jasig.portal.channels.portlet.CSpringPortletAdaptor.renderCharacters(CSpringPortletAdaptor.java:217)
    at org.jasig.portal.ChannelRenderer$Worker.execute(ChannelRenderer.java:631)
    at org.jasig.portal.utils.threading.BaseTask.run(BaseTask.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaInterceptor.invoke(JpaInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at org.jasig.portal.$Proxy249.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Before that????

Comment: Here are the lines before that: TRACE [org.jasig.portal.ChannelManager#156] portlet.DispatcherPortlet.[] Nov/10 09:56:45 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.pluto.internal.impl.RenderRequestImpl@380cf0c
TRACE [org.jasig.portal.ChannelManager#156] portlet.DispatcherPortlet.[] Nov/10 09:56:45 - Cleared thread-bound resource request context: org.apache.pluto.internal.impl.RenderRequestImpl@380cf0c
ERROR [org.jasig.portal.ChannelManager#156] portlet.DispatcherPortlet.[] Nov/10 09:56:45 - Could not complete request